# Bootstrap 3: Add a select list in button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, buttongroup

I am trying to build a small search box using bootstrap button group, in which I want provision to select the field and value to search for. I tried with the following code and the UI is fine. But when I click on the dropdown to select the field (or any empty space), the form gets closed. Is there a way to achieve something like this (without building a custom form etc.)?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Search <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="col-sm-12 dropdown-menu">
        <select class="form-control" >
            <option value="id">ID</option>
            <option value="Name">Name</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <button>Reset</button>
        <button class="pull-right">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krishnasarma/u891Lcrd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the following script in your script section. It will avoid your problem.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').find('select').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

## JSFiddle Link

[http://jsfiddle.net/vinodudhaya/u891Lcrd/2/.](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodudhaya/u891Lcrd/2/)

Comment: I have checked in jsfiddle . Lemme know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the `dropdown` to select the field (or any empty space), the form gets closed because this is how the `.dropdown-menu` of bootstrap works, when you click on the `button.dropdown-toggle` bootstrap add the class `open` to its parent (`.btn-group` in this case) and there is the style:

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {/*at this point the menu is showing*/
    display: block;
}
```

Then when you click anywhere on the page, including the menu itself bootstrap remove the class `open` so the menu is hidden again.

Now knowing how it works lets fix it to achieve what you want, first we have to avoid that the menu is hidden when you click anywhere on it:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I suppose that you still want to hide it when you click on the `button` *Go*, if not forget this part.

```
$('#search-btn').click(function(e) {
    $('.open').removeClass('open');
});
```

Now let's put it all together:

Here a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/trx1ke30/) *fork* from yours

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#search-btn').click(function(e) {
   $('.open').removeClass('open');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Search <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="col-sm-12 dropdown-menu">
    <select class="form-control" >
      <option value="id">ID</option>
      <option value="Name">Name</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <button>Reset</button>
    <button id="search-btn" class="pull-right">Go</button>
  </div>
</div>
```